# Get featured image from any link (without ever needed to upload files to wordpress image library)

Tags: wordpress-featured-image

I have a question about wordpress **Featured Image**. When i need a **Featured Image** for a post of my wordpress site, i must upload the file to wordpress library and choose to make it display. The question i have today is that, is it possible to add a field in wordpress library that says **insert from url** to get file from a link that works for **Featured Image**? Why do i need this option? Because, i want only to add image to **Featured Image** for a post instead of adding the image to the content of a post, and there won't be full of files in my gallery. I noticed that, this option(insert from url) is only available when i'm adding images to post, but not available for **Featured Image**. Any solution for this?